# How to use AND expression with Select Case (VBA)?

Tags: vba, select, case

```
Select case X-value    
      Case Is >= a AND a >= b
```

'X' will be greater then 'a' most of the time. But 'a' is rarely greater than 'b' most of the time.

When I run this select statement, the program is ignoring the AND expression and acting like the entire statement is true when sometimes it's false. Even if I change the "AND" to a "," I get the same result.

Why is my Select statement ignoring my second condition?

Comment: VBA Case Select Multiple Conditions does not answer my question.

Comment: `Select Case True`, `Case X-value >= a And X-value >= b`.

Comment: thank you, this works

Comment: (... oops typo, that second `X-value` should be `a`).

Comment: yep. it works. thanks.